# In R, How to write from a list to file with a set amount of elements on each line?

Tags: r, file-io

Let's say I have a list of 23 elements.

```
ls <- list(1:23)
```

Which I want to write to a file which has 5 elements on each line, separated by a tab until not possible anymore:

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23
```

How would I go about doing this? I don't see any options in write.lines or write.table.

---

The code by @akrun works best:

```
cat(gsub("\\s*((\\d+\\s+){1,4}\\d+)", "\\1\n",
      paste(unlist(ls), collapse="\t")), '\n', file = 'file1.txt')
```

With a minor error for decimal values, as the resulting `file1.txt` looks like this:

```
0.0005862      0.0005983      0.0006225      0.0006637      0
.0006622      0.0006197      0.000599      0.0005983      0
.0006247      0.0006707      0.0006641      0.0006253      0
.0006087      0.0006234      0.0006807      0.0007485      0
.0007546      0.0007      0.000643      0.0006183      0
.0006264      0.0006819      0.000697      0.0006453      0
```

Comment: Try with `matrix(ls, byrow = TRUE, 5, 5)`

Comment: Updated my question a bit, why this probably wouldn't work

Comment: Did you meant `c(1:23)` or `list(1:23)` if it is latter, it is just a list of one element of length 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `cat` and `gsub`. `unlist` the `list`, `paste` them into a single string, insert nextline (`\n`) at every block of 'n' digits with spaces, and use `cat` to write into console

```
cat(gsub("\\s*((\\d+\\s+){1,4}\\d+)", "\\1\n", 
        paste(unlist(ls), collapse="\t")), '\n')
#1  2   3   4   5
#6  7   8   9   10
#11 12  13  14  15
#16 17  18  19  20
#21 22  23
```

or write to a file

```
cat(gsub("\\s*((\\d+\\s+){1,4}\\d+)", "\\1\n",
      paste(unlist(ls), collapse="\t")), '\n', file = 'file1.txt')
```

---

If it is a complex data with scientific notation etc. we could `split` into a `list` and then append `NA` at the end for those elements with less number of elements

```
v1 <- unlist(ls)
lst1 <- split(v1, (seq_along(v1)-1) %/% 4 + 1)
mat1 <-  do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
write(mat1, 'file2.txt')
```

Comment: Works perfectly, how would I change the space separator to a tab in this?

Comment: @B.Quaink you can change the `collapse="\t"`

Comment: This sadly doesn't work when the values are doubles instead of integer though.

Comment: @B.Quaink that needs a different regex i.e. `[0-9.]+` instead of `\\d+` to take care of the `.` as well as the digits

Comment: Alright thanks, getting closer. The 5th element of each row gets stopped at the first `.` and everything trailing gets posted to the next line. It won't do values like `2.000e-05` too. Really appreciate the help :)

Comment: @B.Quaink can you change the options i.e. `options(scipen = 999)` and then use it

Comment: @B.Quaink Can you also try the `split` method I updated

Comment: The output is nicely formatted, but the order of the elements is completely wrong sadly. It seems the 1st element of the 1st row is correct, but the 2nd element in the output is the 5th in the original, the 3rd the 9th etc.. So it looks like : `1 5 9 13...` etc

Comment: I added some extra information in my post to what the issue is and how the .txt file looks like now. It's just the final element that gets cut off

Comment: @B.Quaink Can you post that as a new questions as it seems a bit more different than the one you earlier posted

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define the chunks, I used BBmisc which have `chunk` function to obtain chunks of N elementes (five in your case).
Then you can use write.table witch have the `append` option.

```
library(BBmisc)

x <-list(1:20)
n<-5

splited<-chunk(x[[1]],n)

for(i in 1:length(splited)){
  x=splited[[i]]
  line=paste(x,collapse = "\t")
  write.table(line, file = "output.txt", sep = "\t", 
  row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, append = T)
}
```

Regards