# Add each row of a list the list names

Tags: r, list

I have a list named mylist like:

```
mylist = list(
  a = c("35","45","56",..., "67", "66", "89"),
  b = c("67"),
  c = c("55")
)

$a
[1] "35" "45" "56" ...
[19] "67" "66" "89"

$b
[1] "67"

$c
[1] "55"
```

And I would like to add at the beginning of each list rows the list names. To be like this:

```
$a
[1] "a" "35" "45" "56" ... "67" "66" "89"

$b
[1] "b" "67"

$c
[1] "c" "55"
```

How can I do that?
Thanks!

I could not find a solution yet.

I edited the list how it should be.
Actually, my aim to export this later on as a text file in which each row starts with list names. So I want the output to be like:

```
a 35 45 56 ... 67 66 89
b 67
c 55
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include reproducible data? Particularly with this question, is it important to have a more exact data structure. If you're not sure how to do this, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some tips. Good luck!

Comment: why is `a` added twice in the vector? at the beginning and in the middle? anyway you could do `Map(c, names(mylist), mylist)`

Comment: It seems that you reset `options(width = xx)` so that the 4th element turns to the next line.

Comment: `mylist$a` is just a single vector. The fact that it appears as 2 rows of 3 elements is just an artifact of the way you printed it. Please clarify if you want what your question asks for, that is: put "a" at the start of the list element, or what you show: split `mylist$a` into multiple vectors each starting with "a"?

Comment: So, that's a completely different question. You're asking "how to print a list to a file, printing the name of the current list item at the start of each line". Searching for that in google gives me this question: [Write list to a text file, preserving names, R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8261590/8366499) which you might have to modify if you want to only list N-items on each line, instead of the whole list element – this question might be helpful for that [In R, How to write from a list to file with a set amount of elements on each line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66535035/8366499)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list structure doesn't make complete sense to me for "a". It looks like a single vector yet you want the name ("a") added in more than one place...

In lieu of a reprex, here's an option to add the list name at the beginning using `purrr`.

```
library(purrr)

tmp = list(
  a = c("35","45","56", "67", "66", "89"),
  b = c("67"),
  c = c("55")
)

tmp = imap(tmp, ~ c(.y, .x))

$a
[1] "a"  "35" "45" "56" "67" "66" "89"

$b
[1] "b"  "67"

$c
[1] "c"  "55"
```

*OPs previous comment mentioned exporting the modified list but the comment has been edited. Leaving the code below incase that's something they still want done.*

Export the above list you can run the following.

```
lapply(tmp, write, "tmp.txt", append = T, ncolumns = 7)
```

Example output of "tmp.txt"
[image]

Comment: Please see my modified answer for outputting to a text fie. All you need to do is change `ncolumns = N` to a number that is the same as the length of your longest list item.

Comment: Hi Jamie, it is very close to what I want, but still I am missing the names of list at the beginning of each line. Do you know how to add names to the beginning of each line?

Comment: The code above works for me. I see you edited your initial list, however it is not possible to include `...` in a list that way. Please provide your actual list without the "..."

Comment: It is working for me too, sorry. Thanks very much!